# Semaphores blocking and unblocking

Tags: multithreading, semaphore

I started reading about Semaphore today and have a theoretical question.

Lets say you have 2 threads, thread A and thread B and each has a semaphore, semaphore A and semaphore B. In this *very hypothetical* example the value of semaphore B is -3 and is currently blocked, then thread A issues a B.signal().

What I think I've come to understand in my reading is that semaphore B is now unlocked and is incremented to the value of -2. Will B's thread continue to execute  until it encounters a B.wait() even though the value of the B's semaphore is -2?

Answer (score 0):

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_%28programming%29)

> signal: Increments the value of semaphore variable by 1. After the
>   increment, if the pre-increment value was negative (meaning there are
>   processes waiting for a resource), it transfers a blocked process from
>   the semaphore's waiting queue to the ready queue.

So B is moved to the Os's ready queue and started if there are any free hardware threads (or low priority threads that can be bumped).

But the more serious question is how did you arrive at -3 with only 2 threads ... if A has it should be at zero and when B then wants it then it goes to -1.

Comment: I arrived at -3 because it's a hypothetical question. Plus correct me if i"m wrong, I could've initialized it to -3.

Comment: -3 would mean your already 3 in deficit before starting anything, I can't definitely say its not possible.